# Retrieving html content of an aspx from the codebehind of a custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have 2 files, Test.aspx and MyControl.ascx.

In Test.aspx's html:

```
<MyControl>
  <MyTemplate>
     <div>sample text, other controls</div>
 </MyTemplate>
</MyControl>
```

In MyControl.ascx.cs:

```cs
[ParseChildren(ChildrenAsProperties=true)]
[PersistChildren(true)]
public class MyControl:Control
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    public ITemplate MyTemplate{ get; set; }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        //get the template html, but how to get???
        var templateHtml = this.MyTemplate.ToString();
    }
}
```

I want to get the content of the `<MyTemplate>` tag (`<div>sample text, other controls</div>`) from  codebehind within MyControl.ascx.cs.

Who can help me? Thanks.

Comment: I think your stuck with adding runat=server to access server side.  unless you want to try some javascript/jquery solutions .  javascript can change the value of any element with runat=server , like a hidden field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to make the `div` a server side control as so:

```
<MyControl>
  <MyTemplate>
     <div runat="server" id="divContent">sample text, other controls</div>
 </MyTemplate>
```

Now, in your code behind, depending on what kind of control is this and how is that div rendered, you should be able to do something **like** this:

```
var innerHtml = yourControl.FindControl("divContent").InnerHtml;
```

Again, this depends on how is the div rendered. If it's inside a row (assuming your control is a list of some kind), then you would need to get a reference to the row and then call `FindControl("divContent")` on the row.